# Sending data from Arduino to Blender in python: the data is never received

Tags: python, arduino, blender

I am currently playing with Arduino and I am trying to get simple data to be continuously sent from Arduino to Blender. The problem is in my Blender program, the data is never received.

This is my code in Arduino

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Hello World!");
    delay(1000);
}
```

This is my code in Blender

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages")
import serial
import time

print (" About to initialize ... ")

# open serial port that Arduino is using
s = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=1)

time.sleep(2)
print ("initialize complete")

while True:
    print (s.readline())
```

Comment: Please specify the way you are running blender.
In order to see print messages, you need to run blender from the command line so that the console window is visible.